# how to estimate the fatigue life of a launch vehicle in conceptual or preliminary design?

Tags: end-of-life, vibration

A launch vehicle undergoes vibrational loads during ascent (and descent for reusable ones), how can the fatigue life be estimated in conceptual or preliminary design? Is there any data or standards that specify the vibration levels?

Comment: Seems like finite element modeling of a basic conceptual design would be a good starting point.  But an accurate simulation would require modeling mechanical stress, air flow (and related heating), and temperature related stress.  Whatever program can do all of that accurately is probably very expensive.